# Ubuntu 19.04 profile error: “Find: '/usr/lib/modules/5.0.0-25-generic/kernel/drivers/thermal': File or directory not found”

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, profile

When I start my computer this message appears:

```
Error found when loading /etc/profile:
Find: '/usr/lib/modules/5.0.0-25-generic/kernel/drivers/thermal': File or directory not found
```

I controlled and I don’t have the `5.0.0-25-generic` module folder, I have the 13, 15, 16, 17, 20, 25, 27 and 27, but not the 25.

When I run this command:

```
dpkg -l | grep -E 'linux-image-[0-9]+' | grep -Fv $(uname -r)
```

I get also this line:

```
rc  linux-image-5.0.0-25-generic               5.0.0-25.26                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
```

I read that means that the kernel has already been removed.

How can I correct the problem?

Comment: Uninstall kernel 5.0.0-25.

Comment: this kernel has already been removed, I cannot remove it with apt-get remove

Comment: Try running `sudo update-grub2` on the system.